# Why is the space underneath my theorems not showing up?

Tags: spacing, theorems, mdframed

I styled my `amsthm` theorems with `mdframed`. I tried to add some space before and underneath my theorems with `skipabove` and `skipbelow` as stated [here](http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) on page 6.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, mdframed}

\parindent 0pt
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.95}

\mdfdefinestyle{mythm}{
    backgroundcolor=mygray,
    linewidth=0pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=6pt,
    skipabove=20pt,
    skipbelow=20pt
}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=mythm]{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    This comes before the theorem.
    \begin{thm}
        This is my theorem.
    \end{thm}
    This comes after the theorem.
\end{document}
```

However, the spacing at the bottom doesn't show up.

[image: My theorem without extra space.]

What is going wrong and how can I solve that?

Comment: I think this is a standing bug/feature in `mdframed`, it is really hard to get it to have an even space above an below. Changing to much larger values, the `skipabove` does work, but below, does not

Comment: Might be an idea to email the author, he is usually quite helpful. I think he's also usually on this site.

Comment: Had a closer look, it is definitely a bug, in how styles are defined. If you use `\mdfsetup` instead of defining a style, then it works. This is clearly a but. I'll email the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sent the author the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm, mdframed}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.95}

%
% notice how skipbelow is ignored
\mdfdefinestyle{mythm}{
    backgroundcolor=mygray,
    linewidth=0pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=6pt,
    skipabove=5em,
    skipbelow=5em,
}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=mythm]{thm}{Theorem}

% if we use this instead, it works
% \mdfsetup{
%     backgroundcolor=mygray,
%     linewidth=0pt,
%     innertopmargin=0pt,
%     innerbottommargin=6pt,
%     skipabove=5em,
%     skipbelow=5em,
% }
% \newmdtheoremenv{thm}{Theorem}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant*[2]
\begin{thm}
  This is my theorem.
\end{thm}
\kant*[2]
\end{document}
```